# Best way to send chrome extension channel id to web application

Tags: google-chrome-extension, push-notification, chrome-gcm

I am writing a chrome extension that will receive messages from my application. I have managed to write code to retrieve the push messaging channel id in my extension. Now I need to send this channel id to my application and link it to an account so that I know what user this channel id belongs to.

I have been thinking about the best way to do this. So far I am convinced that I should send the channel Id in a GET request to my application and then ask the user to login via OAuth so I can get their email address and I know who they are.

Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: That's what the samples advise you to do. For example https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/push-sample-app/background.js. Is there something wrong with this approach?

Comment: @sowbug not at all, I was just wondering if there was a better solution.